# how to grep and print whole only first rows if string matches using grep

Tags: bash, grep

Hey i have some data in file.xyz :-

> aa1 completed
>
> aa2 was unsuccessful
>
> aa3 completed
>
> aa4 was unsuccessful
> aa5 was unsuccessful

I want that if i search or grep "unsuccessful" in above file , it only print first row where string i.e "unsuccessful" matches

> aa2 was unsuccessful

How to achieve that?

Comment: In what way does the standard `grep` command not fulfill your requirements?

Comment: standard `grep` behavior does exactly what you're looking for so there must be an issue with how you're using `grep` ... please update the question with the actual `grep` command(s) you've tried

Comment: hmmmm, the question has now been updated to a completely different issue ... we've gone from `grep` does not work to ... `grep` works but I only want to display the first match(ing line); for the new requirement, one very simple fix: `grep unsuccessful file.xyz | head -1`

Answer (score -1):

try this command

```
grep "<string_you_want_to_search>" filename
```

For your case

```
grep "unsuccessful" file.xyz
```

Comment: thanks ..whats the other way to print only 1 row where string matches?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the standart command grep separately like:

```
grep "unsuccessful" file.xyz
grep "completed" file.xyz
```

Or, if you want to search in the same command line for both, use this:

```
grep -E "unsuccessful|completed" file.xyz
```